# I have pygame installed but VSC marks it red

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pip, pygame

I'm a new programmer and have no idea why this is happening.

[image: screenshot.png]

how embarrassing XD

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [what this site is about](https://stackoverflow.com/about) and "[How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)" before asking a question.

Comment: Its all the way to the left, import sys and import os work fine, and shift + alt + f isnt working

Answer (score 1):

You have some amount of spaces before the `import pygame` text on the first line.